# Custom istream end iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to read one line of text from an `istream` and split it into words. My current code is

```
vector<string>((istream_iterator<string>(f)),
                                istream_iterator<string>());
```

where f is an `ifstream` object. However, this reads to the end of the file, and I want to stop it from reading when it reaches a newline. Is there any way to do something like `istream_iterator<string>("\n")` so the vector constructor will stop pushing back when it reaches a newline?

Comment: To read a lime at a time, [`std::getline()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::getline()` to read a single line, and then use `std::istringstream` to read words from that line, eg:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(f, line);
std::istringstream iss(line);
std::vector<std::string> words(
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline` to read each line and push them to your result container

```
std::vector<std::string> lines;
for (std::string line; std::getline(f, line); lines.push_back(line));
```

Edit: Remy Lebeau already answered to OP's question, I want to clarify my code:

Normaly, to read lines in a file we would write something like

```
while (f.good())
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(f, line);
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Since `std::istream` can be [converted to boolean](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), we can rewrite it as:

```
while (f)
{
    std::string line;
    std::getline(f, line);
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

And since `std::getline` return the [input stream itself](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline#Return_value), we can use it as the loop condition:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(f, line))
{
    lines.push_back(line);
} // `line` still can be used after this line, outside its scope
```

But we have to pull the temporary variable `line` outside of its scope. To avoid doing so we use `for` instead of `while` loop and declare `line` inside `for` loop:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(f, line); )
{
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

Finally, since the body of the loop contains only 1 line, we can put it inside `for` loop too:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(f, line); lines.push_back(line));
```

Comment: It’s probably a good idea to explain a little more about what this somewhat dense code does.

Comment: Clarification: I want to read just one line, and split that line into a word vector